# Из фамилии удалить последнюю букву, из имени удалить первую

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список ФИО:

```
КузнецоваК НКлавдия Николаевна
ТарутинА ВАнатолий Владимирович
КлимовД ВДмитрий Вячеславович
КулешовП ВПавел Валерьевич
СуфьяноваЕ ДЕвгения Демидовна
БельтюковА ПАлександр Петрович
ПетровГ ВГеннадий Васильевич
КондрашевД ВДмитрий Валерьевич
```

Как мне удалить последнюю букву из фамилии и первую из имени?

Comment: История ваших вопросов показывает, что вы просто приходите давать задания. Такие вопросы бесполезны для сообщества. Приведите пример кода, которым вы пытались решить задачу.

Comment: @mkkik Для таких вопросов существует специальная тревога. И налагается штраф на участника, который не соблюдает [правила](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5149/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%83%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Похоже вам надо удалить лишние инициалы имени и отчества (буквы в верхнем регистре) - можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

res = [re.sub(r'[А-ЯЁ]{1} [А-ЯЁ]{1}', ' ', x) for x in items]
```

результат:

```
In [156]: res
Out[156]:
['Кузнецова Клавдия Николаевна',
 'Тарутин Анатолий Владимирович',
 'Климов Дмитрий Вячеславович',
 'Кулешов Павел Валерьевич',
 'Суфьянова Евгения Демидовна',
 'Бельтюков Александр Петрович',
 'Петров Геннадий Васильевич',
 'Кондрашев Дмитрий Валерьевич']
```